# Ошибка eslint при экспорте модуля

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babel, webpack4, eslint

Недавно начал использовать готовый сборщик [gulp-sass-starter](https://github.com/andreyalexeich/gulp-scss-starter). Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не могу экспортировать модули. Добавил в объект "env" параметры "amd": true, но не помогло. Кто знает в чем может быть проблема?

```
// Текст ошибки
    Error in plugin "webpack-stream"
    Message:
        ./src/blocks/components/checkbox/checkbox.js
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
    SyntaxError: D:\development\gulp\work\gems-dev\src\blocks\components\checkbox\checkbox.js: Unexpected token, expected ";" (3:7)

      1 | import $ from 'jquery';
      2 | 
    > 3 | module {
        |        ^
      4 |     $('input[type="checkbox"]').wrap('<div class="checkbox">').parent().append('<span class="checkbox__mark fa fa-check">');
      5 | }
        at Parser.raise (D:\development\gulp\work\gems-dev\node_modules\@babel\parser\src\parser\location.js:41:63)
        at Parser.unexpected (D:\development\gulp\work\gems-dev\node_modules\@babel\parser\src\parser\util.js:160:16)
        at Parser.semicolon (D:\development\gulp\work\gems-dev\node_modules\@babel\parser\src\parser\util.js:133:40)
        at Parser.parseExpressionStatement (D:\development\gulp\work\gems-dev\node_modules\@babel\parser\src\parser\statement.js:796:10)
        at Parser.parseStatementContent (D:\development\gulp\work\gems-dev\node_modules\@babel\parser\src\parser\statement.js:298:19)
        at Parser.parseStatement (D:\development\gulp\work\gems-dev\node_modules\@babel\parser\src\parser\statement.js:141:17)
        at Parser.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (D:\development\gulp\work\gems-dev\node_modules\@babel\parser\src\parser\statement.js:860:25)
        at Parser.parseBlockBody (D:\development\gulp\work\gems-dev\node_modules\@babel\parser\src\parser\statement.js:836:10)
        at Parser.parseTopLevel (D:\development\gulp\work\gems-dev\node_modules\@babel\parser\src\parser\statement.js:47:10)
        at Parser.parse (D:\development\gulp\work\gems-dev\node_modules\@babel\parser\src\parser\index.js:43:10)
     @ ./src/js/import/components.js 1:0-40
     @ ./src/js/index.js
    Details:
        domain: [object Object]
        domainThrown: true
```

---

```
// .eslintrc.json
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "amd": true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "es6": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "rules": {
        "indent": [
            "error", 4
        ],
        "linebreak-style": [
            "error",
            "windows"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "always"
        ]
    }
}
```

---

```
// checkbox.js
import $ from 'jquery';

module {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').wrap('<div class="checkbox">').parent().append('<span class="checkbox__mark fa fa-check">');
}
```

Comment: как именно код выглядит? в checkbox.js

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос

Comment: а где ты такую запись видел? и какая связь с eslint? Вроде бы синтаксическая ошибка

Comment: Встроенный анонимный модуль https://frontender.info/es6-modules/

Comment: Пробовал еще делать так 
export default function () {
// Код
}
Но опять ошибка

Comment: Странно, ни разу такого синтаксиса не видел `module {`. а вот `export default ...` должен работать. Какая ошибка в этом случае?

Comment: Ну и повторю вопрос: почему ты думаешь, что ошибка в `eslint`? Судя по стектрейсу упал бабедь, когда попытался все собрать. Возможно стоит посмотреть его настройки

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102455/discussion-between-grundy-and-zebren).